# ExpressJS Using Multer and BodyParser

Tags: express, multipartform-data, multer, body-parser

I have run into an issue where I have a mixed form with string fields and file uploads (Multiple file support) and I figured out that `body-parser` cannot handle `enctype="multipart/form-data"` so `multer` is the better middleware to use, but I'm curious if this type of form enctype is necessary because the file uploads are handled with jQuery and in a separate route when files are uploaded from the file explorer. The only part from the form upload process that is needed is the outputted links to the files being stored. Any advice on what I should do? Should I nest forms?

**Form:**

```
<form action="/app/blog/create" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="date" name="annotationDate" id="annotation-form-date" required>
    <input type="text" name="title">
    <textarea name="body"></textarea>
    <input type="file" id="file-input" name="fileUpload[]" multiple>
    <div class="file-section">
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Create Blog</button>
</form>
```

**BodyParser middleware setup (app.js):**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

/Extract POST Data
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

**JQuery for File Uploads (POST happens on file selection):**

```
$("#file-input").on('change', function(){
        var files = $(this).get(0).files;
        var formData = new FormData();

        for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
            var file = files[i];
            formData.append('fileUpload', file, file.name);
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: '/app/sign',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
                contentType: false,
            success: function(data){
                for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                    console.log('This is the element ' + data[i]);
                    $('.file-section').append("<div class='file-preview'><a href='" + data[i] + "'>" + data[i] + "</a><a href='#' class='remove-file' data-file-link='" + data[i] + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></a></div>");
                }
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log('error ' + JSON.stringify(error));
            }
        });
    });
```

**Routes for `/app/sign` (For file upload processing):**

```
var multer = require('multer');
var multerS3 = require('multer-s3');
   var upload = multer({
        storage: multerS3({
            s3: s3,
            bucket: options.Bucket,
            contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE,
            acl: options.ACL,
            key: function(req, file, cb){
                var fileNameFormatted = file.originalname.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
                cb(null, req.user.organizationId + '/' + uploadDate + '/' + fileNameFormatted);
            }
        })
    });

appRoutes.route('/sign')

.post(upload.array('fileUpload', 5), function(req, res){ 

    var uploadedFiles = req.files;

    var s3FilePath = [];

    for (var prop in uploadedFiles){
        console.log(uploadedFiles[prop].key);
        if (app.get('env') === 'production' || app.get('env') === 'staging'){
            s3FilePath = 'https://files.test.com/' + uploadedFiles[prop].key;
        } else {
            s3FilePath.push(uploadedFiles[prop].location);
        }
    }

    res.send(s3FilePath);
});
```

**`/app/blog/create` (For record creation):**

```
.post(function(req, res){
    models.Blog.create({
        date: req.body.date,
        title: req.body.title,
        body: req.body.body,
    }).then(function(){
        return models.File.bulkCreate({
            fileUpload: req.body.upload
        });
    }).then(function(){
        req.flash('info', 'Blog was successfully created.');
        res.redirect('/app');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Below code

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
   limit: '50mb',
   extended: true,
   parameterLimit: 50000
}));
```

instead of this code in your `app.js`

```
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
     extended: true
 }));
 app.use(bodyParser.json());
```